# Eclipse Egit push/pull fails behind firewall

Tags: eclipse, push, firewall, egit, pull

I am behind a firewall, and cannot pull from a repository. Push is working fine.
The error message I get is

```
 407 authenticationrequired
```

which suggests a proxy authentication errors.
I have set my proxies manually under Preferences > General > Network Connections.

For both http and https my configuration is the same (same server, same port, same user/pass).

[image]

(the same settings were used to configure git cli, which is working fine, there is no typo, have triple checked that.)

The exception is:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://XXXXXXXX@bitbucket.org/xxxxxx/XXXXXX.git: 407 authenticationrequired
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:562)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openPush(TransportHttp.java:435)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1310)
at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java:189)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.ConfirmationPage$2.run(ConfirmationPage.java:209)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

I am able to pull/push to master using git command line without any problems.

My EGit version is 4.10.0.20171022 and JGit version is 4.10.0.20171019.

Anyone got similar problems and a solution?

Comment: Marketplace and update use `http`, not `https`. What do you mean exactly by _"set my proxies manually"_? Have you set that in Eclipse in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections_? Could you add your (anonymized) settings to your question?

Comment: Yes, I have set bot http and https proxies. I have updated the question.

Comment: Thx. Does it work if you use another protocol (e. g. `http` or `git`)?

Comment: Http is not supported by the repository, ssh is blocked by the proxy.I will try git. Actually it did work fine also via Eclipse before I updated EGit/JGit. Seems like a bug.

Comment: EGit 4.10.0.20171022 and JGit 4.10.0.20171019 are versions of the current nightly build. If downgrading EGit/JGit to the latest release does not help, please report it to Eclipse (with a link to your question here): https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&component=Core&version=4.9

Comment: Most strage thing is, that pull fails, push is working...